# Recommended server for JNLP

Tags: java, webserver, jnlp, java-web-start

I have never used JNLP, and I have no web/war server already running so I will install it from sratch:

Which to use?

- GlassFish
- Tomcat
- Apache
- Jetty
- Another?

I wonder if someone already using JNLP could make any recomendation for the server.

I just want a blank page with a button in the middle for starting the application nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I used WebLogic and it is fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use only JNLP you don't need Java server. JNLP is client side. Simple http server like Apache HTTP Server should be OK. HTTP server will be better solution than use of web container/Java EE server because JNLP (usually) is a static content. Even lighthttpd should be enough.

Comment: "JNLP is a static content" Of course, JNLP content *could* also be generated dynamically on-the-fly. (But in this case, that likely isn't necessary.) Other than that, +1.

Comment: I know I need an http server, I was guessing for an advice I thought apache could be the right choice but perhaps I was searching a lighter configuration, because I don't need huge features, just the button and launch the JNLP, thanks

Comment: Herman: so try lighthttpd :] @Jonik: right - added 'usually' to response ;)

Comment: On Windows I'd prefer to use Apache HTTP rather than ported lighty.

Comment: @zacheusz you are right it takes me a download and after two minutes I see that "ported" was a wrong choice, thanks

Answer (score 2):

As already stated any server capable to serve HTTP will do. If your WebStart application is not signed by itself (i.e. you code-signed the corresponding Jar files) you could probably consider to publish the JNLP plus its resources via HTTPS. This way your clients will know that the software they are going to execute came from its rightful origin. Although unsigned WebStart applications are restricted in their privileges on the client's machine it still is a measure to elicit trust in your clients. On the other hand this requires more configuration effort with regard to the server you chose.

If your application will need some extended privileges on the client's machine such as access to the file system then I would recommend that you do sign your jar files to gain the necessary privileges automatically (don't forget to specify them in a  element within your JNLP).

These are the default restrictions for unsigned WebStart apps:

- No access to local disk.
- All your jars must be downloaded from the same host. Note, however, that you can  download extensions and JREs from any host as long as they are signed and trusted.
- Network connections are allowed only to host from which your jars were downloaded. ("Phone home restriction.")
- No security manager can be installed.
- No native libraries (not even in extensions).
- Limited access to system properties. (The application has read/write access to all system properties defined in the jnlp file, as well as read-only access to the same set of properties as applets

Comment: I see, I will need Signed WebStart App.. because application needs  disk access (client), and it even needs many jar files in a lib folder and some dll files to be delivered.

Comment: @Hernán: OK, then you should probably sign it. You don't need the additional HTTPS then and you're free to go with any HTTP-capable server.

Answer (score -2):

You dont need a server to run JNLP(Webstart).. This is how webstart works

it simply is an application that can be started over the web, this would be the procedure from the user perspective:

user goes to yourwebsite.com

user see's link: run my awesome app

user clicks link, which downloads .jnlp file

user runs the jnlp file through java web start (part of java SE, user requires java runtime environment JRE to run this)

java web start reads jnlp to get information about the server that holds the corresponding application

jar files get downloaded automatically (the first time) and then the application starts

user gets bored and closes application

the next day, user comes back and clicks your link again

application is already downloaded, so it starts right away

user gets bored again and closes your application

1 day later, you decide to update your application and you deploy the new jar file on your 
server, replacing one of the old files

after 2 days user clicks your link again

java web start recognizes that the user has a different version, downloads update automatically and starts the application again
...
..
.

Comment: He need HTTP server to serve jnlp files. For example yourwebsite.com ;)

Comment: well i thought that was an obvious bit.

Comment: @DaMainBoss, I don't like this expression but here it applies, your answer is not even wrong

Comment: It's a reasonable explanation of how JWS works but the question was about serving the jnlp file itself.  A server really isn't needed to deliver a jnlp file - you could e-mail someone a jnlp file and it would still work.  Clearly the answer involves a web server of some sort since there's a button involved.

Comment: :D hmmm cool. doesnt still count for a downvote:( as i said and i quote "1 day later, you decide to update your application and you deploy the new jar file on your server, replacing one of the old files"